# How to host laravel4 based app on a shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have read lots of tutorial on hosting laravel 4 based app on shared hosting .But I am not able to deploy it successfully . I am getting following error

```
Warning: require(__DIR__/../bootstrap/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Hosting\10588605\html\healthscape\ideconnect\public\index.php on line 41

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\Hosting\10588605\html\healthscape\ideconnect\public\index.php on line 41
```

I have website in which I want to deploy my app . For example I have this website .

```
http://healthscapeseries.com
```

I want to add my laravel app to this like

```
http://healthscapeseries.com/myappname/public/
```

it should point to my app. Can any one help me out with this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What I understand from your error is, its failing to load the `autoload.php` file, also as you are getting above error means your hosting configurations are correct, now what you have to do to solve above error is print full path of  `__DIR__/../bootstrap/autoload.php` and verify autoload file exists there, also check server logs as well as application logs under `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @GaneshGhalame yes by reading the docs even I figured out that the hosting configuration are correct. So SHould I just echo the complete path to see it ?. Although I can see that the autoload.php file exists in the bootstrap folder

Comment: Yes you have to check path by echoing it or if you have a full path you can paste it in a browser and hit enter if file download it means your path is correct

Comment: @GaneshGhalame I tried to echo the line but it just shows half of the path

http://healthscapeseries.com/ideconnect/public/ please check this link

Comment: so your relative path is not working, Just put full path of your `autoload.php`  like `D:\Hosting\10588605\html\healthscape\ideconnect\app ... path of autoload.php`, once it work you can add relative path using `__DIR__`

Comment: @GaneshGhalame i tried this `require 'D:\Hosting\10588605\html\healthscape\ideconnect\bootstrap\autoload.php';` but it says  syntax error please see the same url

Comment: It means there is some syntax error in your autoload.php I suggest you to debug it just put echo "Return" in autoload. php and comment everything else.

Comment: @GaneshGhalame I tried uploading the whole website again in another folder with this following url

http://healthscapeseries.com/ideonline/public/

Now I am getting symphonny error

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you point to your app like

`http://healthscapeseries.com/myappname`

For attaining this do following steps

1. Create a folder `myappnamebase` in your document folder
2. Put all your contents of the application except the public folder content to `myappnamebase` folder
3. Create new folder in `public_html` named `myappname`
4. Put all your public folder content in `myappname` folder

Then bring the following changes:

Inside  `public_html->myappname->index.php`

instead of

```
 require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

add

```
 require __DIR__.'/../../myappnamebase/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

instead of

```
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

add

```
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../myappnamebase/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Inside `myappnamebase->bootstrap->paths.php` do editting so that it looks like following

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../../myappnamebase/app',

'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html/myappname',

'base' => __DIR__.'/../../myappnamebase',

'storage' => __DIR__.'/../../myappnamebase/app/storage',
```

Comment: Now I have one dedicated domain for the Laravel website , Its here www.ide-portal.com , I have kept the content of public folder in the Html_public and I have create a folder outside ideonline which has all the other data . Can you please guide me to fix this error

Comment: yes i think i can.  In the answer in all the places where you see  "/.../.../"  replace with "/../" . And make pubic directory like  'public' => __DIR__.'/../public'.  This will solve your issue @Vikram